# UTF-8, Unicode in SML/NJ

Tags: unicode, utf-8, sml, smlnj

I am playing with SML/NJ (version 110.99.4) on Windows 10.

I have a structure containing a text file in UTF-8 encoding:

```
...
    let
      val s:string = "søk"
    in
      print s
    end;
...
```

My console has 65001 code page (which is UTF-8) - `chcp` reports it.
This code prints `søk`. Then, I have 3 questions:

1. As I know SML/NJ has `widestring` (and `widechar`) type for Unicode, but it's optional for Windows (actually it is missing), I supposed that `string` is ASCII string, but it seems it is not. So, what is `string` type? Codepoints? UTF-8?
2. How portable is this `string` from SML/NJ? Can I use it everywhere (on Linux, for example) where I want UTF-8?
3. Is this behavior of `string` similar for all SML implementations?

PS. Also my SML/NJ version has UTF8 structure (`open UTF8` passes). It recalls `wchar`. But I see that `string` allows to print non-ASCII strings correctly. At the same time the structure `String` recalls `char`. It confuse me more even: what does `string` contains: `wchar` or `char` (but UTF8)? Then what is the missing `widechar`?

PPS. Attempt to enter non-ASCII string in sml.bat repl's session failed with:

```
stdIn:2.10 Error: illegal non-printing character in string
stdIn:2.11 Error: illegal non-printing character in string
stdIn:2.12 Error: illegal non-printing character in string
...
```

Sorry, for so many questions, I would appreciate any clarification about the state of Unicode, UTF-8 in the world of Standard ML (and SML/NJ) and convenient ways to work with them.

Comment: `string` does not have an encoding. If you look at `explode "søk"`, you will find that it has four elements; two of them represent the 'ø'. That these are displayed as 'ø' is because your editor and console both interpret them that way, and SML has no part in it.

Comment: It makes sense. @molbdnilo do you know some SML implementation supporting Unicode? I read yesterday a lot of mail SML-related mail threads but I have feeling that Unicode is not supported..

Comment: I doubt it – it's a very niche "academic" language. I think your "best" option would be to switch language to F#. (Of course, it also depends on what you mean by "support". Do you want actual Unicode strings or is "Unicode encoded in UTF-8" strings good enough?)

Answer (score 1):

I found for instance, such library:
https://github.com/cannam/sml-utf8 which defines `WdString`. It allows to encode/decode to/from UTF8/wide-string and other "standard" (for SML) string operations. I tried it with SML/NJ and it seems it works.